# Can we access non-static method of Non-static nested class from static nested class

Tags: java

I have written following code. Can I access (non-static) method m1() of class NestedClass2??

```
class OuterClass
{
   static class NestedClass
   {
     static class NestedClass1
     {
       class NestedClass2
       {
          void m1()
          {
             System.out.println("Non-static method of NestedClass2");
          }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to access it?

Comment: In main method of another class.

Comment: And where is the `NestedClass4` (NC4) ? Is it a different program on its own or it is also nested in `OuterClass`?

Comment: Most **importantly**, you must know that `non-static methods cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: Sorry it's m1() method of NestedClass2.

Comment: Please edit the question and add that.

Comment: If non-static methods cannot be referenced from a static context then what is the use of writing non-static member in nested static class?

Comment: If you know what `static` and `non-static` means, you should be able to answer that yourself. Again your main question is not clear , please revise it so that it gets attention.

Comment: The answer you got isn't complete. You can create instances of NestedClass2 outside of Outer class. You just have to get the syntax right. Google is your friend here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to invoke `NestedClass2.m1()` from another, independent class (in this example I invoke it from `Main`) you need to create instances of `NestedClass1` and `NestedClass2`.

In the below example, take a look on how to create a `non-static` class instance of an inner class (`nc1.new NestedClass2()`) versus how to create a `static` instance of an inner class (`new OuterClass.NestedClass.NestedClass1()`).

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OuterClass.NestedClass.NestedClass1 nc1 = new OuterClass.NestedClass.NestedClass1();
        OuterClass.NestedClass.NestedClass1.NestedClass2 nc2 = nc1.new NestedClass2();
        nc2.m1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> To instantiate an inner class, we must first instantiate its enclosing
>   class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this syntax:
>
> OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();

So,

1. Create instance of NestedClass1 first.
2. Create instance of NestedClass2 with above given syntax.

   ```
   class AnyOtheClass {
       public static void main(String args[]) 
       {
           OuterClass.NestedClass.NestedClass1 objNestedClass1= new OuterClass.NestedClass.NestedClass1();   
           OuterClass.NestedClass.NestedClass1.NestedClass2 objNestedClass2= objNestedClass1.new NestedClass2();
           objNestedClass2.m1();
       }
    }
   ```